# Is it possible to get information about forks in the blockchain?

Tags: bitcoind

I don't know if "fork" is the right word here, but I know that two blocks can be mined around the same time, creating more than one competing block at a certain level of the blockchain.

Is it possible to get information for about these competing blocks from bitcoind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

Run `bitcoin-cli`[`getchaintips`](https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-reference#getchaintips).

Comment: Note that not all orphan blocks will necessarily be propagated all around the network, so that might make hinder statistical analysis.